# Switch to other function when an error occurs and program breaks in R

Tags: r, glm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exception handling in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622777/exception-handling-in-r)

I use `glm.nb` function to fit an NB model, but sometimes the program gives an error:

`Error in while ((it <- it + 1) < limit && abs(del) > eps) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

The whole program then breaks down. Now I write another function that can address such convergence issue (it's due to extremely large likelihood value; see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749977/why-does-glm-nb-throw-a-missing-value-error-only-on-very-specific-inputs)).

My question is: how can I tell R to switch to my own function when the `glm.nb` function breaks down?

I was told to look for the error message in the source code of `glm.nb` and then modify that part. However, I didn't find such codes explicitly, and wonder if there is an easier way in R to jump out of a breaking-down function and switching to another function by some `if-else` statements?

Comment: I suggest this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622777/exception-handling-in-r

Comment: @xin guo: thanks! I also find this link very helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440373/functions-and-try-in-r?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Two posts answer this question (thanks you @xin guo for pointing out the right direction):

[catching an error and then branching logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158780/r-catching-an-error-and-then-branching-logic)

[Functions and try() in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440373/functions-and-try-in-r)

On my experiments, I notice the differences when you use `warning = function(w)` and `error = function(e)` in `tryCatch()`. If there is only warning, then the error part won't be recognized, and vice versa. Make sure you get the correct message from R, and use corresponding argument in `tryCatch()` :)